# How to import an existing a pdf file and then rearrange the order of the pages using TCPDF -PHP

Tags: php, node.js, pdf, tcpdf

I am able to create a pdf document using TCPDF and then re-order the pages.  But what I would really like to do is import a pdf document that was not created using TCPDF and re-order the pages for that document.  I have been searching the documentation for TCPDF but I can not find a way to read in a pdf file for page re-arrangement. Please, can someone advise?  I am happy to consider other libraries/framework in different server-side languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/fpdi) to import pages and use them in TCPDF or FPDF.